# Is it possible to use a Taylor expansion to approximate x2/x1?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have the expression $\frac{x_2}{x_1}$ which I would like to linearize, ie. ($a.x_2+b.x_1+...$).  Can I use a Taylor expansion to do this?

Comment: What do we know about $x_1$ and $x_2$ ? If they are near $1$ , for example , we can apply a 2-dimensional taylor-expansion.

Comment: It is not possible near $x_1=0$ (as you seem to be wanting). It is possible near other number $x_0$, but then would have the form $$x_2(a_0+a_1(x-x_0)+a_2(x-x_0)^2+\cdots)$$

Comment: I guess what I am looking for is a 2-d Taylor expansion for $f(x_1,x_2)$ around (1.0,1.0).  Let me pursue that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables) for the development of Taylor series in several variables.

Applied to the case
$$f(x,y)=\frac xy \qquad \text{around} \qquad x=a \qquad \text{and} \qquad y=b$$  the formula will give
$$f(x,y)=\frac a b+\frac{1}b(x-a)-\frac{a }{b^2}(y-b)$$